# Trouble getting to Desktop directory, with Bash on Microsoft's Windows (WSL)

Tags: ls, desktop, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using the Bash terminal for Windows and currently this is what I get when I type `ls -a`

```
<username@userPC>:/$ ls -a
. bin data home lib64 mnt root srv usr
.. boot dev init lost+found opt run sys var
acct cache etc lib media proc sbin tmp
```

I'm trying to get to my desktop and I don't know what path that is.  I tried to go through each of these files and had no success.

Comment: Do you have the Windows Subsystem for Linux or CygWin or something else?

Comment: Yea.  It's WSL..

Comment: It is /home/your_username

Comment: I can't see my desktop files.

Comment: If you are trying to get to your *Windows* desktop files from WSL, then you may find this useful: [Can I change directory to a Windows drive in Ubuntu Bash on WSL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831361/can-i-change-directory-to-a-windows-drive-in-ubuntu-bash-on-wsl)

Comment: Note: LSW does not use/contain Linux: It is Gnu/Linux, without the Linux. (but people often, confusingly, call Gnu/Linux “Linux”.

Comment: Your *Windows* Desktop files??? @OnurOzbek

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about Windows Desktop files.